# Connect to running qemu instance with qemu monitor

Tags: qemu

I'm having an instance of `qemu` running on Windows 7, running without an open terminal. Now I want to shutdown the machine with the name *MyMachineName* or add an USB-Device to it. 
I need a scriptable solution. Libvirt is not a solution, because it has other disadvantages for my system.

Im looking for a magic line like:

```
qemu-monitor -connect=MyMachineName command="shutdown"
```

How can I do it?

Comment: So, you saying, that I can do the following: `qemu-system-... -monitor "/dev/ttyMyConsol"` and than `echo "My QemuMonitorCommand" > /dev/ttyMyConsol` and it will make qemu execute the command on that machine? but the only way to control the machine is the qemu-monitor?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Someone might be able to chime in with a proper command for operating on TTYs, but I'll post a solution in the meantime involving the network.

There are a couple options for redirecting the QEMU monitor. One way is to have QEMU offer access to its monitor via telnet:

```
$ qemu-system-i386 -monitor telnet:127.0.0.1:55555,server,nowait;
```

Then, QEMU can be scripted by piping commands to `telnet`. This is fine as long as the output of commands can be discarded since the telnet session will probably close too quickly for visual feedback:

```
$ echo system_powerdown |telnet 127.0.0.1 55555
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
$ _  # qemu sends the guest an ACPI shutdown signal
```

If the output of the commands executed on the monitor need to be collected, a TCP session can be used instead:

```
$ qemu-system-i386 -monitor tcp:127.0.0.1:55555,server,nowait;
```

Then, commands can be sent to the listening monitor via `netcat` or a similar utility:

```
$ echo info\ kvm |nc -N 127.0.0.1 55555
QEMU 2.11.0 monitor - type 'help' for more information
(qemu) info kvm
kvm support: enabled
(qemu) $ echo system_powerdown |nc -N 127.0.0.1 55555
QEMU 2.11.0 monitor - type 'help' for more information
(qemu) system_powerdown
(qemu) $  # hit return
$ _  # qemu sends the guest an ACPI shutdown signal
```

Here is a link to partial documentation of QEMU monitor commands: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Monitor

Comment: This method is insecure, and actually, the QEMU website discourages it for production environments (just saw it yesterday, but don't have the link any more). Instead, the QEMU folks recommend to talk to QEMU via unix domain sockets (as in @boann's answer) or to authenticate and encrypt network connections via TLS.

Answer (score 40):

My preferred way to do this is to connect to the QEMU "monitor" via a UNIX socket. It works well, although the method is very poorly documented.

When you start QEMU, add the `-monitor` parameter as follows:

```
$ qemu-system-i386 [..other params..] -monitor unix:qemu-monitor-socket,server,nowait
```

`qemu-monitor-socket` here is not a keyword, but a host path and filename of your choice to represent the socket on disk. You'll see this file created when QEMU starts.

The options `server,nowait` tell QEMU to listen for connections, but start the VM without waiting for a connection.

You can use the **socat** utility (available from all good repositories) to connect to the socket to type commands to the QEMU monitor prompt:

```sh
$ socat -,echo=0,icanon=0 unix-connect:qemu-monitor-socket
QEMU 2.8.1 monitor - type 'help' for more information
(qemu) _
```

What socat does is connect two arbitrary streams/sockets together. The first parameter `-` is a synonym for `stdio`, i.e., the console keyboard and output. The couple of options `echo=0,icanon=0` make keyboard interaction nicer here by preventing re-echoing of entered commands and enabling <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion and arrow keys for history. The final parameter says to connect to the socket file created earlier.

To send a one-shot command to QEMU, *echo* it thru socat to the UNIX socket:

```sh
$ echo "info status" | socat - unix-connect:qemu-monitor-socket
QEMU 2.8.1 monitor - type 'help' for more information
(qemu) info status
VM status: running
(qemu)
$ _
```

For cleaner output in a script, I also add `| tail --lines=+2 | grep -v '^(qemu)'` to filter out the first line and the `(qemu)` prompt lines:

```sh
$ echo "info status" | socat - unix-connect:qemu-monitor-socket | tail --lines=+2 | grep -v '^(qemu)'
VM status: running
$ _
```

To shut down the VM as you wanted, useful monitor commands are `system_powerdown`, which presses the on/off button of the imaginary machine so it can gracefully shut down, or `quit`, which quits QEMU immediately.

A couple of notes:

- QEMU also permits `-qmp` in place of `-monitor`, providing a JSON-based interface; that might be more robust for programmatic control, but I never tried it.
- A socket file on disk is always empty. It doesn't store data; it's just an arbitrary handle for programs to open communications.

Comment: This gives a newbe some more useful informations how qemu works with sockets! =)

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for! One thing though, your clean output could be simplified to `| tail -n1 | head -n1`

Comment: This solution is very nice because we can set appropriate permissions on the socket (if qemu doesn't by default) so that nobody else than root can send commands to the VM; the accepted answer does not care about that. However, an additional question: Can we somehow have a "shell" where we enter qemu commands (in contrast to echoing them into a pipe at the normal command line)?

Comment: @Binarus The first example with socat above gives you the interactive shell.

Comment: Shame on me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Got “Inappropriate ioctl for device” following these examples? You might have run into a socat bug. Try swapping its arguments. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/socat/+bug/1883957

Comment: `echo`ing to the socket didn't work well for me under macOS. Instead of passing in e.g. "info status" it would get just the first character followed by a reversed-color percent "i[%]" or "s[%]" instead of "system_powerdown". It seems like the command is getting sent before the monitor is ready to receive it or…something? I was able to workaround by adding (to `nc` actually) a 1-second delay between things: `echo system_powerdown | nc -i 1 -U ./my-monitor-socket` 

Comment: Found via https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/687632/42732 a simpler workaround: `(echo system_powerdown && sleep 1) | nc -U the-socket` which likely also works around it in any `socat` equivalent too. So I guess it's not the command getting *sent*, but that the sending side of the socket getting *closed* too early that somehow troubles it.

Comment: re: security: in addition to having permissions, it also seems to be a lot harder to accidentally expose a unix socket to the internet than a port bound to localhost (@Binarus) this is also a question where more than one answer deserves the "correct" tick, but apparently that's not possible and deemed very very bad