# How to get the hostname and IP address of a VM using qemu-guest-agent

Tags: kvm, qemu

I am running a VM using

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -accel kvm,thread=multi -cpu host -smp 1 -m 2048 \
-drive file=ubuntu-server1.qcow2,if=virtio -vga virtio -display none -daemonize \
-nic bridge,model=virtio-net-pci,mac=DE:AD:BE:EF:E0:00
```

To get the IP address I have to use:

```
ps -ef | grep qemu
arp | grep -i DE:AD:BE:EF:38:C4
ip neigh | grep -i DE:AD:BE:EF:38:C4
```

After, reading the [wiki](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/GuestAgent), I have installed and enabled `qemu-guest-agent` in the guest.

```
sudo apt install qemu-guest-agent
sudo systemctl start qemu-guest-agent
sudo systemctl enable qemu-guest-agent
```

I have run the VM using

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -accel kvm,thread=multi -cpu host -smp 1 -m 2048 \
-drive file=ubuntu-server1.qcow2,if=virtio -vga virtio -display none -daemonize \
-nic bridge,model=virtio-net-pci,mac=DE:AD:BE:EF:E0:00 \
-chardev socket,path=/tmp/qga.sock,server,nowait,id=qga0 \
-device virtio-serial \
-device virtserialport,chardev=qga0,name=org.qemu.guest_agent.0
```

So, the socket is in `/tmp/qga.sock`.

Now I am not understanding how to use this socket to get the hostname and IP of the guest.

Just to be clear, I have checked [How to find the IP address of a KVM Virtual Machine, that I can SSH into it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33191/206574) , but I am not interested to use `virt-manager`.

Comment: I also asked this question on QEMU mailing list and the answer is on https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/qemu-discuss/2022-01/msg00050.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [QEMU documentation](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/GuestAgent#Example_usage) example, `socat` can be used to query the guest agent's API over its socket. As everything appears to be in JSON, better have the `jq` tool installed too.

> ```
> mdroth@illuin:~$ sudo socat unix-connect:/tmp/qga.sock readline
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> {"execute": "guest-info"}
> ```
>
> [...]

The command above gives among other things the list of all possible commands that can be sent.

On my Debian system, the [*readline* feature is disabled in `socat`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/socat/socat.1#READLINE), and man page tells to use `stdio` (alias `-`) instead. Alas, sometimes the output doesn't happen or is incomplete and I suspect `socat` doesn't handle optimally EOF conditions in this case. Adding a delay in the left side appears to fix this.

This becomes (as root or an adequate user):

```
{ echo '{"execute": "guest-info"}'; sleep 2; } | socat unix-connect:/tmp/qga.sock -| jq .

[...]
      {
        "enabled": true,
        "name": "guest-network-get-interfaces",
        "success-response": true
      },
[...]
```

One can now send `{"execute": "guest-network-get-interfaces"}` and with some filter (and [some training](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)) using `jq`:

```
# { echo '{"execute": "guest-network-get-interfaces"}'; sleep 2; } |
      socat unix-connect:/tmp/qga.sock - |
      jq -j '."return"[] | ."name", (."ip-addresses"[] | " ", ."ip-address","/",."prefix"),"\n"'
lo 127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128
ens3 192.0.2.2/24
```

Error handling for null values (interfaces without address) is left as an exercise.

For the hostname part, it's easier, there's a single value. The command is `"guest-get-host-name"`:

```
{ echo '{"execute": "guest-get-host-name"}'; sleep 2; } | socat unix-connect:/tmp/qga.sock - | jq  -r '."return"."host-name"'
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the delay afterwards! I was having trouble (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426652/connect-to-running-qemu-instance-with-qemu-monitor?rq=1#comment1311788_476617) where the monitor would only get one character of my command before closing with a weird reverse-rendered (`tput rev`-style) % sign. I thought to try a sleep *before* my echo which didn't help, but the sleep **after** does!