# How do I force reset (from the host) a VM started with qemu-system-x86_64?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, pxe, remote-management

I have a Windows VM that is stuck on the blue reset screen. Usually in this situation I just kill the process for the VM, but obviously that isn't ideal.

It seems that they way to do this is through the qemu monitor console. However, I am not sure how to access it.

- I don't have virsh, so virsh commands are out.
- I am running with GPU passthrough, so ctrl-alt-2 doesn't switch to the qemu monitor.
- I thought this might be the answer, but it brings up an iPXE prompt instead of a (qemu) prompt. [Connect to running qemu instance with qemu monitor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426652/connect-to-running-qemu-instance-with-qemu-monitor)
- I tried subsituting the machines IP in the command described in the above answer, but that also resulted in a iPXE prompt.
- From this iPXE prompt ctrl-alt-2 switches to a black screen with a solid cursor and no ability to type.

Edit: As requested, here is the command I used to start the VM:

```
vmname=win10
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 \
-name $vmname,process=$vmname \
-machine type=pc,accel=kvm \
-cpu host,topoext,hv_relaxed,hv_spinlocks=0x1fff,hv_vapic,hv_time \
-smp 8,sockets=1,cores=4,threads=2 \
-m 32G \
-rtc clock=host,base=localtime \
-serial none \
-parallel none \
-nographic \
-vga none \
-device vfio-pci,host=09:00.0,multifunction=on \
-device vfio-pci,host=09:00.1 \
-device vfio-pci,host=0a:00.0 \
-device vfio-pci,host=45:00.3 \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=/tmp/my_vars.fd \
-boot order=dc \
-drive file=/dev/NVME-TANK/ntfs-zvol,format=raw,if=virtio \
-drive file=/home/boss/ISOs/virtio-win-0.1.208.iso,index=2,media=cdrom \
-netdev type=tap,id=net0,ifname=vmtap0,vhost=on \
-device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0,mac=00:16:3e:00:01:01
```

Comment: I guess if you gave the exact way this VM was started by giving the exact qemu command used (with all of its myriad of options). This would possibly help some people understand why you don't get the qemu prompt.

Comment: I don't see any `-monitor unix:[...]` parameter like in the linked Q/A's answer, so there might not be any way currently with `socat`. Next time, as in the linked answer add the `-monitor` parameter.